# red5 rtmp stream not smooth

Tags: rtmp, red5

I get a problem using red5 server. 
   I use red5 server (1.0.5 version) to play an mp4 file with RTMP streeam.
   However, the video is not smooth; at first, I thought it could be caused by the bandwidth, then I run red5 on localhost, the video is not smooth there either.

The mp4 file is in streams folder, and I use JW player to play it. What's more the audio is OK.

Because I am a beginner with red5 and I even don't know where to start to solve the problem, so any help or suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks!

Here is the 
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efH1P.png)

ps: forgive me for my poor English。

Comment: Check your task manager or top to see if you are maxing out your cpu; the server will drop video frames if it cannot keep up. Also the buffer full / empty messages can occur if your logging is turned up to high, set to WARN or INFO and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have checked my task manager,the cpu is just fine, and the logger level is WARN and INFO, but the problem still exist.

Comment: Here I tried other mp4 videos files, problems seems different, in these cases,they continusly give me a Buffer.Empty / Buffer.Full. And They just use little time to finish playing videos,They are played  fast forwarded, And when finish it in a quick time, the videos became a still image untill the end time of the video. So,could it be the matter of the timestamp?

Comment: sorry, I think I have found where I was wrong. I think it is caused by the mp4 file itself. When I use red5 to play my mp4 files,  I found the Metadata - seekpoints in log is wrong, I found from Internet that it means the keyFrame of video which is in milliseconds, so this explains when I use the other mp4 files the last elements of seekpoints is just little than the duration, however, in my mp4 file, the value of the last elements of seekpoints is much samller than the duration(just about 1/50 ). I think that is the point

Comment: Following above, Then I asked  my colleague who is responsible for the recoding of the mp4, He said that in our mp4 file, the seekpoints means the localtion of keyFrames , and there is a keyframe every 50ms,So I guess that is why the last element of seekpoints is just about 1/50 compared with durations. I think red5 takes it as milliseconds. So, It seems that my vedio is played fast forward can also be explained.                                  So,do you think that is the point to cause my problem?  Wish I coult get more suggestions. THK.

Comment: MP4 format normally uses microseconds for timing; Flash uses milliseconds. Try a regular mp4 like the ones in the oflaDemo.